# Creating a vector in R including characters and operators

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector, data-manipulation

I would like to assign a vector in R to write less code and ensure there are no mistakes in the code.
I want to exclude observations `"obs 1", "obs 4", "obs 9"` etc. using the `subset()`-function. However, I want to create a vector of these observations to use in the `subset()`-function instead.

**Example - how I would like it to be:**

```
excluded <- column1!= "obs 1" &  column1!= "obs 4" & column1!= "obs 9"
dataframe <- subset(dataframe, excluded)
```

***Example - What works and what I want to avoid***

```
excluded <- column1!= "obs 1" &  column1!= "obs 4" & column1!= "obs 9"
dataframe <- subset(dataframe, column1!= "obs 1" &  column1!= "obs 4" & column1!= "obs 9")
```

I have tried both `c()`, `list()`, the combination of them both, and `column1 <- "column1"`.

*Thank you in advance!*

---

Update with data set example.

```
set.seed(42) 
n <- 12
dataframe <- data.frame(column1=as.character(factor(paste("obs",1:n))),rand=rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2), x=rnorm(n))
dataframe

#output -first 5 rows:

   column1  rand      x
1    obs 1    A  1.37096
2    obs 2    B -0.56470
3    obs 3    A  0.36313
4    obs 4    B  0.63286
5    obs 5    A  0.40427
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible data set?

Comment: Of course! I have updated the question now.

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a logical vector and then using it to subset. The `%in%` operator avoids repetition.

```r
excluded <- c("obs 1", "obs 4", "obs 9")

subset(dataframe, !(dataframe$column1 %in% excluded))
#    column1 rand           x
# 2    obs 2    B -0.56469817
# 3    obs 3    A  0.36312841
# 5    obs 5    A  0.40426832
# 6    obs 6    B -0.10612452
# 7    obs 7    A  1.51152200
# 8    obs 8    B -0.09465904
# 10  obs 10    B -0.06271410
# 11  obs 11    A  1.30486965
# 12  obs 12    B  2.28664539
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that `%in%` avoids repetition. However, then the vector cant be used with other data frames?

Comment: Yes. See edited answer to use it with other dataframes, basically just choose the rows in a character vector.

Answer (score 1):

```
# load package
library(data.table)

# set as datatable
setDT(dataframe)

# put exclusion criteria into vector
y <- c("obs 1", "obs 4", "obs 9")

# subset
dataframe[!column1 %in% y]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. The observations are not removed. I have updated my initial post with a dataset.

Comment: @vickitinka Thank you for the re-producible example. It is because you have a column named `x` inside `dataframe`. Therefore `data.table` is confused. Try naming the exclusion vector to something different, say, `y`, as I have done in updated example

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize. Thank you! Now it works in the example. However, I realized in the real data this doesn't work. Does it matter if it is an -markdown file or not?

Comment: np. Could you please mark as an answer so question could be closed